# position indepdendent code for shared object file under cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, position-independent-code

We created a shared object file and linked to our executable:

```
add_executable(a ${A_SRC})
add_library(testso SHARED src/mainlib.cc test1.cc test2.cc)
target_link_libraries(a, testso)
```

we notice that the code is compiling without `-fPIC`, but the link uses `-fPIC`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -c -i../../src ./test1.cc
g++ -std=c++11 -shared -fPIC ../mainlib.cc test1.o -o testso.so
```

Is the `-fPIC` flag required on each file?  Will we crash at some point or is this ok?

Comment: What versions of `cmake` and `g++` are you using?

Comment: Note that the use of `$(A_SRC)` is deprecated. You should be using `${A_SRC}` instead (I've never used `$(...)`, so I'm not certain on how it works, so it might be slightly different than that)

Comment: Sorry, I typed a shortened version and messed that up. The variables are using curly braces